# Media query not respected on mobile device?

Tags: css

In head section i have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:640px) and (min-device-width:1025px)">
```

Final result is that i want enable css in page only when windows min-width > 640px and not is a mobile/smartphone/tablet device, just only monitor for pc/notebook.
The problem now is: why not work in mobile device with 240x340 px screen? In this case i should load page without css, but in my mobile (a Samsung gt-s5222) it load same the css.
I suppose that this mobile ignore about 'media query' and load same css. How i can then solve this problem?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally not use media queries in the . Just use one sheet and put the queries in there:

Styles.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
.cssstuff {
display:none;
}
}
```

Perhaps the browser doesn't understand a media query like you use it in the  .

Comment: Good. Thanks very much. So in my mobile not load css. Just last thing. There is some "bug" in this solution? I tell so for be to sure that the result are egual for all device except for all Windows with width > 640px.

Comment: Glad it helped. Media queries should work on all devices. You can check the  official syntax here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Don't forget to upvote if the answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the `device` of `min-device-width:1025px`?

Comment: I use min-device-width:1024px for force to load css stylesheet only on monitor with width-resolution > 1024. This property should exclude all device with resolution <= 1024.